# How to improve performances in UIPath?

Tags: uipath

How to improve performances in UIPath? What are the activities can we use in automation to increase performance speed? List out the activities that should be avoid.

Answer (score 4):

First, it is always a good idea to program your RPA with visible actions to make sure that you can achieve the result that you want while seeing the workflow in action, then you can increase performance switching between the input methods (Default, SimulateType, SendWindowMessages) so you can make your RPA work in the background.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuyRjiXLaRc

As of the output methods, avoid using OCR activities as much as you can since they will slow down your process comparing to (Full text, native).
https://studio.uipath.com/docs/output-or-screen-scraping-methods

If you are working in a citrix environment and you want to interact with an element that doesn't show up immediately avoid using the delay activity since it could not show up in the amount of time that you have programmed, use the wait image activity instead.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EmaQ_BLwgaw